# minimal class to help you raise exception?

Tags: python, exception

What does the following class does:

```
class HException(Exception):
        def __init__(self, value=''):
                self.value = value
        def __str__(self):
                return self.value
```

I saw it being called by `raise`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is custom exception for more precise designations problems.
Not just an abstract exception. But an exception has arisen in a particular subject area.

```
class MoneyTransactionException(Exception):
    ...
```

says that something wrong with money manipulate in program.

[User defined exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions)